# Tenable Nessus and SecurityCenter installlation/configuration issues

Tags: redhat, httpd, rhel7, nessus

I've installed Nessus and SecurityCenter on a RedHat 7.5 instance by following the user guide from Tenable.  I'm able to get to the Nessus interface which is served on port 8834, create the admin login, and choose "SecurityCenter Manged" but I cannot access SecurityCenter on port 443.  I have verified that a listener was added on 443 during the installation but continue to get a 403 error which states "Forbidden, You don't have permission to access / on this server."  I've read on the Tenable site that SecurityCenter ownership for all child files/directories should be tns:tns so I tested that but no change was noticed.  I tried restarting SecurityCenter but it failed to restart due to httpd process already running.

```
 Unit SecurityCenter.service has begun starting up.
Dec 31 22:24:45 ip-10-0-1-14.ec2.internal SecurityCenter[11327]: Starting SecurityCenter services: Error starting. Daemons still running: httpd
Dec 31 22:24:45 ip-10-0-1-14.ec2.internal systemd[1]: SecurityCenter.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 31 22:24:45 ip-10-0-1-14.ec2.internal SecurityCenter[11327]: [FAILED]
Dec 31 22:24:45 ip-10-0-1-14.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start SYSV: Starts and stops the Lightning daemons.
-- Subject: Unit SecurityCenter.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit SecurityCenter.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Dec 31 22:24:45 ip-10-0-1-14.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Unit SecurityCenter.service entered failed state.
Dec 31 22:24:45 ip-10-0-1-14.ec2.internal systemd[1]: SecurityCenter.service failed.
Dec 31 22:24:45 ip-10-0-1-14.ec2.internal polkitd[591]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:11321:1420671 (system bus name :1.104, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Au
```

I stopped the httpd service but it wouldn't restart due to a failure of Jobd.php process to start.

Any information or further troubleshooting help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Any relevant SELinux messages ?

Comment: I disabled SELinux.  I have since uninstalled everything and started over with slightly different results.  This time I installed SecurityCenter first, verified that I could access the UI on port 443.  Next I installed Nessus and found that I could not access the UI.  I manually ran the start command for nessusd service, /opt/nessus/sbin/nessusd start,  and then I can access the UI on port 8834.  The issue is that the terminal session is frozen  while the nessusd service is running.  As soon as the Terminal session expires or I <ctrl -C> or <ctrl -Z> break the process the UI is inaccessible.